# client server socket programming not reponding

Tags: python, sockets

My question is,this sample web socket python program is not responding.I also tried with local host as server address where I put IP and still result was the same please help

server code :
import socket

```
server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
server_address=("192.168.1.105",8081)

print ('Starting up on %s port %s' % server_address)

response=None

try :

    server.bind(server_address)
    server.listen(5)
    connection,client_address=server.accept()
    print ("connection from" % connection.getpeername())

    data=connection.recv(4096)

    if data:
        print ("recived ", repr(data))

        data=data.rstrip()
        connection.send("%$\n%$\n%$\n" % ('-'*80,data.center(80),'-'*80) )

    connection.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RD | socket.SHUT_WR) 
    connection.close()
    print ('Connection closed()')

    server.close()

except socket.error as msg:
    response=msg


print (response)
```

client code :

```
import socket


s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.168.1.105",8080))
v=bytes("HI man","utf-8")
s.send(v);
data=s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print(data)
```

output : 
server  =Starting up on 192.168.1.105 port 8081
client  =b ' '

(Python version 3.3)

Comment: my python version is 3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `Python 2.7` and code works for me is as below.

```
import socket

server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
server_address=("127.0.0.1",8081)

print ('Starting up on %s port %s' % server_address)

response=None

try :

    server.bind(server_address)
    server.listen(5)
    connection,client_address=server.accept()
    print ("connection from " + str(connection.getpeername()))

    data=connection.recv(4096)

    if data:
        print ("recived ", repr(data))

        data=data.rstrip()
        connection.send("%s\n%s\n%s\n" % ('-'*80,data.center(80),'-'*80) )

    connection.shutdown(socket.SHUT_RD | socket.SHUT_WR)
    connection.close()
    print ('Connection closed()')

    server.close()

except socket.error as msg:
    response=msg


print (response)
```

Client

```
import socket


s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1",8081))
v="HI man"
s.send(v);
data=s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print(data)
```

Some errors in your code like listening on `8081` and sending data on `8080`, I correct others errors also. Please try this must work on yours.

Comment: Thanks for your help , i tried this code but it raise this error 
Starting up on 127.0.0.1 port 8080
[WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by it
s access permissions

Comment: You dont have permission on this port. Please try another port like `9999` or `10099`. Try until server starts

Comment: How do i do that , i smply run this server.py in cmd and this is the out put 
Starting up on 127.0.0.1 port 8080
[WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by it
s access permissions

Comment: Open that `server.py` and change `8080` to `9999` or other port no.

Comment: Thanks man its working on 9999 port but i got another error may be i can solved it out thank for your help u save me

Answer (score 0):

you tried to connect to port 8080 and not to the servers's 8081 port

Comment: i change port on cline.py(to 8081) while server.py is running then python raise an error as followes : 
ConnectionResetError: [WinError 10054] An existing connection was forcibly close
d by the remote host

Comment: i doubt that when i used debug in eclipse its not responded after 
connection,client_address=server.accept() line , is something i have to change in my code or pc setting??

Answer (score 0):

I am also using Python 3.3 . To solve your problem let us first make you server accept connections from any NIC and let your client connect to server through loop back IP address.It seems that port 8080 is not available.Please try this modification of your code and let me know

Server:

```
import socket

server=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
server_address=('',5000)

print ('Starting up on',server_address)

response=None

try :

    server.bind(server_address)
    server.listen(5)
    connection,client_address=server.accept()
    print ("connection from ",client_address)

    data=connection.recv(4096)


    if data:
        data=data.decode()

        print ("recived: ", data)

        data=data.rstrip()
        reply="%s\n%s\n%s\n" % ('-'*80,data.center(80),'-'*80)
        connection.sendall(reply.encode())


    connection.close()
    print ('Connection closed()')

    server.close()

except socket.error as msg:
    response=msg

if not response:
    print("Program success")
else:
    print (response)
```

Client

```
import socket
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("127.0.0.1",5000))
v="HI man"
s.send(v.encode());
data=s.recv(1024)
s.close()
print(data.decode())
```